# Automatically calculated height is always zero and tableview cell items leading and top constraints not satisfied in autolayout - Xcode Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to get three labels in a UITableview cell to each take up a third of the superview's width, hugging the top and sides. The constraints I've added are 0 from the leading and top for the first label, 0 from the top and centre X for the second, 0 from the top and trailing for the third, and width = 1/3 of the superview's width for all of them. For another UITableview cell with three labels and the same constraints there is no issue but this cell just doesn't want to work.

I've tried adding >= height constraints, creating a new cell with new labels, removing the tableview content insets, deselecting the adjust scroll view insets option in the view controller, cleaning the build file, and restarting Xcode with no luck.

[image]

There is also an error for each label in the Storyboard saying they're missing y and x constraints but if I click "Add missing constraints", nothing changes. As you can see, the leading and top constraints are set to 0 (not to margins) and the X and Y values it automatically sets it to are 15 and 11 respectively.

MAIN ISSUE:

When I try to run the code for the UITableView heightForRowAt:, it comes back with a calculated height of 0 for that cell. I'm assuming that these issues are related but may be wrong.

Btw I'm coding in swift if I need to do anything programatically.

If you need anymore information let me know.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using UIStackView?

Comment: I've just looked into that and it would work perfectly if I knew the number of cells, but I need to use a tableview cell as many times as the relevant data needs which I can't figure out how to do in the stackview :/

Comment: Add labels in stack view and then add the stack view to table view cell?

Comment: Just tried that and although it removes the issue of the X and Y positions, it still produces a tableview cell with a height of zero. I thought these issues were connected so I will change my question to fit this. Thanks for your support though, I've never worked with stackviews and didn't realise how much simpler they are than tableviews!

Comment: Just tried putting the stackview into the tableview cell and it works! If I'm ever using views with proportional views in the future I'm definitely using stackviews! Thanks very much for your help :)